# CSS hover to show text

Tags: html, css

My hover is on the image but how can I make the text stay shown until I move mouse outside the container not the image?? and how can I make the text appear from under the image, "z-index" is not working

```
.hover-image:hover + .info {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

you can see what I mean here:
https://jsfiddle.net/edrees/wb5f4muj/6/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

You need position not static in order z-index to work

```
z-index: -1;
position: relative;
```

EDIT: in order to have text hoverable as well, you need to wrap the hover image and text with the div and add hover styles to it.

In that case hover will happen on both image and text.

Comment: when i wrap them in a div and add the hover on it, it works even if am not hovering on the image, i want it to work only when hover on image